# Generating predictions on training data in GBM regression

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, boosting

I am fitting a GBM based regression model in R with a Gaussian loss function. The problem I face is that after fitting the model,  the predicted values generated on the training dataset do not exhibit a lot of variation i.e. Q1,Q2 and Q3 are almost the same. However, the predictions generated by the same model on the test data seem to well "spread-out".

Just to be thorough, I also ran a linear regression and generated predictions on the same training data to test the variability in predictions. The predictions seem to be well "spread out".

I am not sure if I am generating predictions from gbm correctly.

Here is an example using the mtcars dataset for generating predictions on the training data using both gbm and lm-

```
library(gbm)
# load mtcars data
data(mtcars)
# fit GBM
gbmFit2<-gbm(mpg~cyl+disp+hp+wt+qsec,
             data=mtcars,
             distribution = "gaussian",
             interaction.depth=3,
             bag.fraction=0.7,
             n.trees = 50)
# generate predictions
p1<-predict(gbmFit2,n.trees=50)
# summary of actual values
summary(mtcars$mpg)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  10.40   15.42   19.20   20.09   22.80   33.90 
# summary of predictions from GBM
summary(p1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  19.88   19.88   20.03   20.09   20.33   20.33 
# linear regression
regFit2<- lm(mpg~cyl+wt,data=mtcars)
# summary of predictions from linear regression
summary(predict(regFit2))
  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 10.32   16.10   19.66   20.09   25.04   28.83
```

Comment: You might want to add a tag for R on here as well - that may get you more useful input from people looking for R-specific questions.

Comment: Done! Also added a comparison to linear regression

Answer (score 3):

The issue is the number of trees you are fitting in relation to your learning rate.

You do not provide a learning rate to your booster (called `shrinkage` in the R library), so the model assumes the default of $0.001$.  This means you are fitting 50 trees, and the contribution of each is shrunk by $0.001$, so you're really only getting about $0.05$ of a tree.

You need to fit many, many more trees when using boosting.

```
library(gbm)
data(mtcars)

M <- gbm(mpg~cyl+disp+hp+wt+qsec,
         data=mtcars,
         distribution = "gaussian",
         interaction.depth=3,
         bag.fraction=0.7,
         n.trees = 10000)

p <- predict(M, n.trees = 10000)
summary(p)
```

Results in

```
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  13.24   15.19   18.97   20.09   25.93   26.86
```

To tune the appropriate number of trees, you should fit many more than you think are neccessary, then use cross validation to assess the optimal number to use for predictions.  Here's an example you can running using your data.

```
M <- gbm(mpg~cyl+disp+hp+wt+qsec,
         data=mtcars,
         distribution = "gaussian",
         interaction.depth=2,
         n.minobsinnode = 2,
         bag.fraction=1.0,
         n.trees = 50000,
         cv.folds=3)

gbm.perf(M)
```

Given the very small size of your data set, it would be a good idea to bootstrap this entire cross-validation process many, many times to assess the stability of your decisions.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that there is little to no deviation in your fit data (p1) indicates that the model explains very little of the variability in the original data set (it's fitting the mean, but that's about it).

R-squared, or Adjusted R-squared (which penalizes for number of parameters in the model) are standard was of measuring how much variability from the observation set has been captured by the model (Editorial note: this is a useful metric, but should never be seen as a substitute for out-of-sample validation since co-linearity and overfitting can lead to very high R-squared values but poor predictive accuracy).

You can get the r-squared stats from your model in R as follows:

```
summary(gbmFit2)$r.squared
```

You can see a number of other fit properties by examining the full model summary with

```
summary(gbmFit2)
```

This is standard functionality for most modeling capabilities within R (lm, glm, etc.).

These will give you a better indication of the extent to which your model is explaining the input data.  If you are getting large variation in predictions outside of the training set, this could indicate that you have explanatory variables that are deviating significantly in order to explain a small number of data points but have zero or near-zero influence for most of the training points.  If this is a prevalent effect (your out-of-sample predictions have much more variability than your in-sample back-fit), it may indicate that your training data is not representative of the input space.

The summary commands listed above will also tell you about the significance (t-stats) of included explanatory variables.  That may give you a better indication of which of the included predictors is responsible for high variability in your prediction set.  The fact that they do not produce a lot of variability in your training set is likely an indicator that those factors are not prevalent or impactful in the majority of training samples as stated above.

As a final note - all of the foregoing comments would hold true for any model - regardless of its underlying fit mechanics or functional form.

Comment: Please see the edited question above

Comment: Generally true but not applicable in this situation. Drury's response is spot on.